# What are examples of approaches to dimensionality reduction of feature vectors?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, representation-learning, principal-component-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

Given a pre-trained CNN model, I extract feature vector of images in reference and query dataset with several thousands of elements.

I would like to apply some augmentation techniques to reduce the feature vector dimension to speed up cosine similarity/euclidean distance matrix calculation.

I have already come up with the following two methods in my literature review:

1. Principal Component Analysis (PCA) + Whitening
2. Locality Search Hashing (LSH)

Are there more approaches to perform dimensionality reduction of feature vectors? If so, what are the pros/cons of each perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dimensionality reduction could be achieved by using an **Autoencoder** Network, which learns a representation (or Encoding) for the input data. While training, the reduction side (Encoder) reduces the data to a lower-dimension and a reconstructing side (Decoder) tries to reconstruct the original input from the intermediate reduced encoding.

You could assign the encoder layer output ($L_i$) to a desired dimension (lower than that of the input). Once trained, $L_i$ could be used as a alternative representation of your input data in a lower feature-space, and can be used for further computations.

[image: Autoencoder Architecture]

Comment: Maybe this answer could be further improved if you link to a paper or implementation that shows the application of AE to reduce the dimensionality of feature vectors. If you consider images feature vectors, then, in a way, AE are commonly applied to reduce the dimensionality of images (or feature vectors), but what if the inputs are not images?

Comment: Is there any python library perform autoencoder efficiently?

Comment: @FäridAlijani Not that I know of. However, designing one in Keras wouldn't be much of a task. The following Keras blog might help : 
https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

Answer (score 2):

Some examples of dimensionality reduction techniques:

| Linear methods | Non-linear methods | Graph-based methods ("Network embedding") |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PCA CCA ICA SVD LDA NMF | Kernel PCA GDA Autoencoders t-SNE UMAP MVU | Diffusion maps Graph Autoencoders Graph-based kernel PCA (Isomap, LLE, Hessian LLE, Laplacian Eigenmaps) |

Though there are [many more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction).